# Divide a row into column when any charcter find in a row

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

I want to divide the row into the columns, starting a new row each time the `New Data` phrase is found in the file:

Input

```
New Data
52.6114082616
41.8319773432
75.6986111112
74.6176129172
New Data
100.0
100.0
100.0
8.00000000003
99.7916666667
42.435664564566
```

Output

```
52.6114082616 41.8319773432 75.6986111112 74.6176129172
100.0 100.0 100.0 8.00000000003 99.7916666667 42.435664564566
```

I have tried with `xargs`:

```
awk '{print$1}' file.txt  | xargs -n2 echo
```

but this will not include blank lines, and I want the blank lines as well.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind editing your question to include the desired output for your example input? It will make it much easier for contributors to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Guarav Yadav, I have edited your question to show what I  think you mean. Please would you check that it's correct, and if not, please [edit] it.

Comment: @Gaurav Yadav the point being in particular what you mean with "and I want the blank lines as well"

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk` to provide alternate separator:

```
awk '/^New Data/ {sep=ORS; next} {printf "%s", sep $0; sep=OFS} END{print ""}' file
```

If the record matches regular expression `^New Data`, `sep` will be changed to `ORS`/newline, otherwise `sep` will be `OFS`/space.

Comment: If you change `sep=ORS` to `if (NR>1) sep=ORS` it'll avoid printing a blank line at the start of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Using perl :

```
$ perl -lne '$\=" ";if (/New Data/){ $\="\n"; s/.*//g; } ;print $_;print "\n" if eof' file

52.6114082616 41.8319773432 75.6986111112 74.6176129172 
100.0 100.0 100.0 8.00000000003 99.7916666667 42.435664564566
```

Answer (score 0):

POSIX sed. In the sed's pattern space we accumulate all the lines read until we meet the New Data containing line. At which point we Print and Delete the pattern space and go back to the top of sed script for more. The thing to note is that we behead the leading New Data line from the pattern space. The test command t shall keep converting tge newlines to spaces till we meet the next New Data. Then the cycle repeats.

```
sed -e ':a
  $!N;/^New Data\n/D
  /\nNew Data$/! s/\n/ /;ta
  P;D
' file
```

GNU sed: Here we accumulate the non New Data lines in the hold space. Upon encountering the New Data line (drop its first) we fetch what was stored in the hold + null the hold. Then change all newlines to spaces.

```
sed -e '
  /^New Data$/!{H;$!d;}
  1d;z;x;s/.//;y/\n/ /
' file
```

Perl in the slurrp mode: we read in the whole file into the perl's pattern space $_.

Options:

```
: `-0777` slurps the input intob$_. 
: `-l` sets   ORS = RS = \n
: `-a` autosplits the pattern space ibto fields and pytsin @F array. 
 `-n` no print the pattern space by default.
: `-F` specifies the field delimiter used to split the pattern space.
```

Special Variables:

```
 : `$"` value is space by default.
 : `$\ ` output record separator newline
 : `$#F` index of the last element of tge array @F, indices start from zero. 

perl -F'/^New\hData\n/m' -lan -0777e '
  print join $", split $\ for @F[1..$#F];
' file 


perl -lne '
  push @A, $_ if ! /^New Data$/;
  print join $", splice @A if eof || // && $.>1;
' file 


perl -lpe '
  ($_, $p, $\)
    = /New/ ? ($p, undef, defined $p ? $/ : $,)
    : ! eof ? ($p, $_,    defined $p ? $" : $,)
    :         (qq[$p$"$_], "foo", $/)
    ;
' file
```

Output:

```
52.6114082616 41.8319773432 75.6986111112 74.6176129172
100.0 100.0 100.0 8.00000000003 99.7916666667 42.435664564566
```